What is the ruling on going to hajj vs helping someone you care for?
If  i have to choose between helping a person who need's immediate assistance to save his life like some medical emergency and doing hajj, what should i choose.That person not be any random person but a person i cares for.Could be a random person to w i developed an emotional attachment.What is the the preferred way to deal with such a case by most scholars in Islam?
